# d3 tree graph load with expand active or only one branch only

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am using D3.js with Angular. below is my component. which produce below output.

**How I can open only one active branch as expand (for example: Only Level2: B branch should load as expand and Level 2: A branch should load a collapsed.**

[image]

```
expand('Daughter of A');

function expand(d){
  if(d._children){
      d.children = d._children;
      d.children.filter(function(d) { return d.name.indexOf("SpecialNode") > -1; })
                .forEach(expand);
      d._children = null;
  }
```

}

Comment: Difficult to say anything without seeing some code. d3 will display the data you provide to it. My suggestion based in your example to is to add some boolean property to your items like `showChildren` and add some flow control.

Comment: trying like this .. code added

Answer (score 0):

Add a Boolean property to each datum called expand, set it to true for root level and level 2 B and check it when you call expand. Recursively set expand for all children to true when you expand their parent node, so that they too can be expanded in the future.

```
function expand(d){
  if(d._children){
      d.children = d._children;
      d.children.filter(function(d) { 
          const toExpand = d.expand;
          d.expand = true;
          return d.name.indexOf("SpecialNode") > -1 && toExpand; 
      })
      .forEach(expand);
      d._children = null;
  }
```